# Cosine distance between same vectors not equal 0

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to retrieve the nearest neighbors of a vector from a list of vectors, using :

> neigh = NearestNeighbors(metric='cosine')
>
> neigh.fit(list)

From what I've read and witnessed if **vector1** and **vector2** have the same exact value across all dimension, the distance retrieved from these two vectors will be equal to 0. I'm using the **kneighbors** method to find the distance.

> neigh.kneighbors(vector_input)

However, in some cases (not all cases) even if both vectors are equal, the distance retrieved is not equal to 0 but some tiny numbers like 2.34e-16.

---

> **len([i for i, j in zip(vector_from_list,vector_input) if i == j])** returns the dimension of the list meaning that each i-index element is equal to the i-index element of the other vector. Therefore, the vectors, if I'm not wrong, are totally equal.

The dtype for all vectors is np.float64

---

Is the method to find the distance not consistent ? Or did I overlook something (a parameter, for example) in scikit method ?

Comment: The epsilon machine for numpy is near what you find: #2.22044604925e-16. It's usually used to avoid division by zeros in numpy.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm finding or some multiple of this value, I guess there is no workaround for this ? In my case, I really want to add a condition based on this value (if distance = 0)

Comment: don't do dist = 0  condition but rather dist<min. that way you can avoid this epsilon machine without changing something else. For example set min to 10e-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's an expected behavior.

If you want to use a condition if distance is equal to zero consider using ***numpy.isclose***. For example,

```
import numpy as np

a = 2.34e-16
b = 1.7e-14 # both tiny values, almost zero
print(a==b) # prints False
print(np.isclose(a,b)) # prints True
```

You can set how close you want the value to be by setting other parameters of the function. See [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html#numpy.isclose) for more.

Alternatively, you can also use python's built-in function ***math.isclose***. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/math.html#math.isclose).
Example,

```
import math

a = 2.34e-16
b = 1.7e-14 # both tiny values, almost zero
print(math.isclose(a,b, abs_tol=1e-10)) # True
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That might be able to solve my problem. I'll try to find the highest "distance" retrieved and put it as the tolerance parameter.